# Swipe between various table views added as subviews of a single View Controller using segment control

Tags: ios, swift

I wish to add a segment control which has various table views associated with its indexes. These table views have been added as subviews of a single View Controller.

Now I want to let the user swipe between these table views by swiping on the view containing them and when a swipe is performed the segment control is updated accordingly as well.

I am also trying to use a custom segment control using this tutorial : http://www.appdesignvault.com/custom-segmented-control-swift-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to keep the datasource and delegate separate for all different tableViews.

1. Add tableview inside a view (You can use XIB).
2. Set custom class of the view.
3. Set delegate and datasource of your tableView.
4. Animate your view on tap of segment controller.

Comment: Yes I also plan to keep the data source and the delegates of the table views different so the state of the table views is retained when switching unlike in the App Store where its loses its stats and you have to scroll all the way down again.